# VB Mysql Fatal error encountered during command execution

Tags: mysql, vb.net, fatal-error

Trying to input values into `MySql` through `VB` when I got this strange error:

> "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

I've attached the code below and am new to using `VB` to `input` into `MySql`.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
Dim conn As MySqlConnection
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
Private Sub ClientBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClientBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.ClientBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Murpha83_dbDataSet1)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Murpha83_dbDataSet1.client' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.ClientTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Murpha83_dbDataSet1.client)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim oForm As Form3
    oForm = New Form3()
    oForm.Show()
    oForm = Nothing
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim Query As String
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString =
   "server=mysql.scss.tcd.ie;user id=murpha83;password=gh8ht6789;database=murpha83_db"
    conn.Open()
    Query = "INSERT INTO client (client_username, name, address, email, DOB, password, employee) Values (@a, @b, @c, @d, @e, @f, @g)"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", clientUsername.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", cusName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", address.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", email.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", DOB.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", employee.CheckState)
    'Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(("INSERT INTO client VALUES ('" & clientUsername.Text & "', '" & cusName.Text & "', '" & address.Text & "','" & email.Text & "','" & DOB.Text & "''" & employee.CheckState & "')"), conn)
    'Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
    MsgBox("Success....", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "SUCCESS")
    clientUsername.Clear()
    cusName.Clear()
    address.Clear()
    email.Clear()
    DOB.Value = Today
    employee.Text = "Unchecked"
End Sub

Private Sub cusName_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cusName.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clientUsername.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Label7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label7.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Has it ever worked?  That is not the correct connection string.

Comment: No I haven't gotten it to work as of yet!